# Regex for field name at ArcGIS JS API infoTemplate creation

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, regular-expression

I'm trying to make same dynamic content builder, but I'm not too experienced. This function sets the content for an infoTemplate of a sublayer(arcgisdynamicservice). It works well, if I hardcode the attribute field name like: `graphic.attributes["SDE.SDE_ESRI_EP_FEATURECLASS_XX.FIELDNAME"]`

I have never used regex in this type of app. Is it working at all, or did I miss something?

```
  function _getPopupTextContent(graphic) {
    let regex = /SDE.SDE_ESRI_EP_.*_XX.VALUE/;
    console.log(regex.test("SDE.SDE_ESRI_EP_FEATURECLASS_XX.FIELDNAME"));  
    //true      running when i'm clicking on the feature
    let popupContent = "<div style='padding:5px;background-color:rgb(251,183,46)'><b>" +
    "</b></div>" +
    "<table style='width:100%;'>"
      if (graphic.attributes[regex]){
        console.log("found") //not logging
        popupContent += "<tbody><tr><td id = 'attrtd'><b>AssetKKSCode</b></td><td id = 'attrtd''>" +
                          graphic.attributes[regex]
      }
      
        popupContent += "</td></tr>" +
                        "</td></tr>" +
                        "</a></td></tr>" +
                        "</tbody></table>"
    return popupContent;          
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a regex? `Graphic.attributes` is a JavaScript object so you can use a string to get the attribute value, e.g. `var myFieldName="MYFIELDNAME"; graphic.attributes[myFieldName]`. Use curly braces to include an attribute value in a popupTemplate e.g. `"<em>{MYFIELDNAME}</em>"`

Comment: Sorry, i totally misnamed here the graphic.attribute properties' naming. I changed it now.
So i dont care about the 'FEATURECLASS'. is just want to check if there is that fieldname. I changed my tactics, i'm trying now with this:
          for (const property in graphic.attributes){
            let tableName = (property.toString()).split(/[_.]/)[4];
            if (graphic.attributes["SDE.SDE_ESRI_EP_"+tableName+"_MV.MYFIELDNAME]){
popupContent +=graphic.attributes["SDE.SDE_ESRI_EP_"+tableName+"_MV.MYFIELDNAME"]

this for loop sy adds this line to the popup to many times(len(obj.prop))

Comment: This curly braces linking didn't work for me somewhy. 
function _joinAndCreateInfoTemplate(){
            if (popupName == 'featureClassName'){
              popupName = new InfoTemplate();  
              popupName.setTitle("<b>${SDE.SDE_ESRI_EP_"+title+"."+re+"}</b>");
              popupName.setContent(_getPopupTextContent);
            }
            
            subLyrObj.infoTemplates[subId] = {
              infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate(popupName)
            };

Answer (score 1):

```
      function _getPopupTextContent(graphic) {       
    let popupContent = "<div style='padding:5px;background-color:rgb(251,183,46)'><b>" +
    "</b></div>" +
    "<table style='width:100%;'>"
    console.log(graphic.attributes)
    for (var property in graphic.attributes){
      var tableName = (property.toString()).split(/[_.]/)[4];
      var fieldName = (property.toString()).split(/[_.]/)[6];
        if(fieldName == 'FIELD1'){
          popupContent += "<tbody><tr><td id = 'attrtd'><b>Fieldname1</b></td><td id = 'attrtd''>" +
          graphic.attributes["SDE.SDE_ESRI_EP_"+tableName+"_MV."+fieldName]
        }
        if (fieldName == 'FIELD2'){
          popupContent += "<tbody><tr><td id = 'attrtd'><b>Fieldname2</b></td><td id = 'attrtd''>" +
          graphic.attributes["SDE.SDE_ESRI_EP_"+tableName+"_MV."+fieldName]
        }
    }
        popupContent += "</td></tr>" +
                        "</td></tr>" +
                        "</a></td></tr>" +
                        "</tbody></table>"
    return popupContent;
```

So the regex was really unneeded for this, but i used it for proper slicing, and i made a variable for the tablename and for the fieldname. So i could check if the fieldname exists, but the name of the table doesn't matter when i check the object's props.